# How to restore deleted panel on desktop

Tags: 10.10, gnome-panel

I had two panels. One panel contains "Applications", "Places", "System", time and date, Gnome network manager icon, and sound icon. The other panel contains different workspaces, the windows of aplications that have been open within the workspaces, show desktop icon and trash bin icon.

I accidentally delete the panel that contains "Applications" and etc. I was wondering how I can restore that panel?

Thanks and regards!

My OS is Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click on the panel which is present on the desktop and uncheck the option "Lock Panel"
2. Right click again on the panel and select "Add New Panel".
3. Once the new panel is added, right click on the panel and "Add to panel" .  A window will pop up with the list of applications for the panel.
4. Select "Main Menu", "Notication Area", " Indicator Applets" and " Sessions Indicator".
5. Close the Window. If you wish, you can lock the panel to avoid deleting it again.

Hope this helps.